# Is it best to group similar media queries at the end of the CSS or to just keep them separated within the CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm just learning html and css and have just completed a landing page project.  When I reviewed my css at the end, I realised that I had multiple media queries all for the same conditions (max-width) but applied to different elements.

I know that you can put multiple elements within a media query but what is best practice?

Currently I have each separate media query located just after the setup css for that element

i.e. #header is followed by @media (max-width:640px) #header{stuff;}}

Comment: I usually do it at the end to keep the code cleaner. I do the same with @keyframes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Media queries were introduced in CSS3 are used for responsive CSS over different media types. Since usually the CSS code itself is applied for describing the presentation of the document or page, responsiveness is a separate feature altogether, so usually they are kept separate at the end of the CSS formatting codes. However, let me answer this question by stating the usage of both of the formats mentioned in the question.

### At the end of code

Most templates of CSS available online usually keep their media queries at the bottom of the entire code making it easier to access and work with the responsiveness feature. Whenever the focus is more on **"chasing device-widths"** then this type of coding practice helps.

As observed, this allows to group together many basic CSS attributes that are applied over many elements.

Also, considering the cascading nature of CSS, the styling below usually (not always, refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to know more) overwrites the styling present above. With `@media` queries present at the bottom of the stylesheet, it allows easy overwriting of relevant styles present above.

Finally ,as mentioned by @rguttersohn, media queries along with `@keyframes` are kept at the end with `@keyframes` usually above `@media`. This makes coding cleaner and easier to comprehend by others as well.

### Below relevant styling counterparts

If styling is more **layout-centric**, it's highly useful to place `@media` queries next to their styling counterparts. This allows ease in editing the style and its corresponding `@media` query both in a single go.

This does mean that there is slightly more code, but these too can be cut down by grouping at breakpoints and section ends.

This type of styling is rarely seen in templates available online, however it's an ongoing trend.

**To Summarize:** I personally am of the opinion to keep all of the `@media` queries together at the bottom, but if I had to divide the labor of styling, I would opt for keeping the styles and `@media` queries together.

Also, given the broad and opinionated scope of this question, I think no answer can determined as right or wrong. I hope this answer brings enough light and information to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your summary!

Comment: @Michelle, if the answer helped, kindly upvote the answer. Cheers :)

Comment: Because I'm a new user, it says that the upvote has been recorded but won't be displayed publicly.